# PyBluez examples yells OsError on Windows

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, pybluez

I've just installed PyBluez on my windows 8 laptop, and I've tried to launch the module examples to test if it works properly.

When I run the `examples/simple/inquiry.py` file I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages>python C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyBluez-0.22\examples\simple\inquiry.py
performing inquiry...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyBluez-0.22\examples\simple\inquiry.py", line 13, in <module>
   duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)
  File " C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 15, in discover_devices
  devices = bt.discover_devices(duration=duration, flush_cache=flush_cache)
OS Error
```

My bluetooth is turned on, and I have no idea of what's going on.

Any help?